# PHP script to know whether receiver's email id is registered paypal id or not?

Tags: php, email, paypal

I am integrating PayPal payment gateway on my site. My issue is:

I want a php script with the help of which, before transaction, I can verify whether the email id, user is providing, is registered PayPal id or not. If email id is not PayPal registered id I can generate a error message pop up window to show that you can not make this payment because email id is not registered PayPal id.

Please help me.

Thanks & Regards
Atul Rai

Answer (score 0):

Use the Instant Payment Notification (IPN) service they provide, you can verify afterwards, not before.

[IPN Introduction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using mass pay. could you please give me a script and steps to implement it so that I can verify the receiver's email id and if receiver's email id not registered I can cancel the transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you could use IPN for getting such information. However, the idea of verifying if the email id is valid paypalId during payment is a bit confusing, as even though you dont have an account, you can create one during the checkout process.